# Django 'locations_extras' is not a registered tag library

Tags: django, django-templates, django-cms

I'm trying to write a template tag in an app I created to use in another app's template.

1. Both apps are most definitely in INSTALLED APPS
2. My app is listed before the other in that list
3. I've restarted the server
4. My templatetags folder has an **init**.py (double underscore, but SO is formatting it)

What am I doing wrong?

```
-locations
   -admin.py
   -apps.py
   -models.py ..etc etc
   --templatetags
     - __init__.py
     - extras.py
```

Template file:

```
{% load locations_extras %}
```

Comment: Have you included `register = template.Library()` in your extras.py? Also, why are you using an underscore in your `load`? You don't have to prefix the app in which you wrote the tags to use it in another one

Comment: @Snackoverflow yes I have the register = template.Library() in my extras. I'm not sure what you mean about the load? Are you saying I can just put extras, instead of locations_extras? that doesn't make a ton of sense. What if another app has extras? Or how does it know which app to look in?

Comment: I see, if you want to do it like that, then you should also prefix your templatetag file name. So extras.py -> locations_extras.py

Comment: @Snackoverflow that did the trick thank you